# Proof of the product rule of limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, epsilon-delta

In the proof of the product law of limits, (by the ε-δ definition, I mean) you assume:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)= L \qquad \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = M$$ and want to prove that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (f.g)(x)= L.M$$
​
By the definition, we got to find an $δ$ such that given an $ε>0$,

$$| x-a | < δ  \Rightarrow   | f(x).g(x)-L.M | < \varepsilon$$

After some manipulation, we get :

$$ | f(x).g(x)-L.M | <  | f(x) | .  | (g(x)-M) | +  | M | . | f(x)-L | $$

Then, in the proof, we usually let $δ_1=1$ and proceed from there.

My question is: Why do we have to assume first that $δ_1=1$?

My suggestion would be:

Let, for some $δ_1,  | f(x)-L | <   \frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | } $

Then, we would get

$$| f(x).g(x)-L.M | <  | f(x) | .  | (g(x)-M) | +   \frac{ \varepsilon }{2}$$

$$| f(x)-L | <   \frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | }$$

Because of this assumption,

$$| f(x)-L | <   \frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | }  \Rightarrow   | f(x) | <  \frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | } + | L |$$

Now we got

$$| f(x).g(x)-L.M | < ( \frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | }  +  | L |  ) . |  (g(x)-M) | +  \frac{ \varepsilon }{2}  $$

If we just let, for some $δ_2, |  (g(x)-M) | <  \frac{ \frac{ \varepsilon }{2} }{( \frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | } +  | L | ) }$, wouldn't that let us say that

$(| f(x).(g(x)-M| +  | M | .  | f(x)-L |) <  \frac{ \varepsilon }{2} +  \frac{ \varepsilon }{2} =  \varepsilon$? (choosing the minimum between the $2$ deltas)

that means that your delta restrictions would have some $x'$s on them. Is that a problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use $ to use latex

Comment: "For some $δ_1,  | f(x)-L | <   \frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | }$ "..I assume you mean "For some $δ_1, |x-a|<\delta_1 \implies  | f(x)-L | <   \frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | }$. Now, since your final choice of delta is $\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ i.e., given an $\epsilon>0$, you'll have delta which is minimum of $2$ deltas such that when $x$ lies in neighborhood of this delta we'll get $|fg-LM|<\epsilon$ but what exactly are these two deltas, the way you have defined them is just the "definition"....

Comment: ... I mean why do that much, just consider a number $\delta_k>0$ such that $| x-a | < δ_k  \Rightarrow   | f(x).g(x)-L.M | < \varepsilon$. Problem solved...Yes?..No. The existence of such $\delta_k$ is not guaranteed unless you explicitly define to be some constant or a function of $\epsilon$. In the same manner, the existence of your $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ is questionable.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake, you interpreted it right. And you were clear! But you say "The existence of such δk is not guaranteed unless you explicitly define to be some constant or a function of ϵ"... and i defined all my deltas based on ϵ... x doesn't appear anywhere... what is the problem? You are saying i have ALWAYS to start with a contant to make my deltas "real? is that it? But if they depend only on ε i cannot see where the problm is. I could see if my deltas where defined as a function of x. Thank you for your answer btw!

Comment: The theorem states " For every $\epsilon>0$ **there always exists** a real number $\delta>0$ such that....." That means you'll always get **a positive real number** for a given value of $\epsilon$ (with the help of $\delta$ you defined). In your case, let's say I give you a value of epsilon, say, $\epsilon =2$. Now, since your delta is $\min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ you first need these two deltas but sadly you just assumed that $\delta_1$ is such that.....  and $\delta_2$ is such that...... You whole work of finding these deltas is still left...

Comment: And without them you can never answer how close do you want $x$ to be to $a$ so that $fg$ belongs to $(LM-2,LM+2)$ ,i.e, you can't get the real number values of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ for a given value of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok! i understand all my work is left for me to do. But if i do that work and define a δ1 and a δ2, my answer will make sense? i mean, is just the case that my answer leaves work to do, or is it that it is wrong? You are touching the heart of my question... because logically, the proposition that is the definition of a limit lets the δ to be defined as a function ϵ (because δ appears after ϵ) . In that sense, my answer would not be wrong, it would just be incomplete ( as you said). Is that the case?

Comment: I wonder why in your proof you didn't use the given limits. You just had to state that such $\delta_1$ exists because  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)= L$ i.e, for every $\epsilon_1>0$ there is a number $\delta_1>0$ such that when $| x-a | < δ_1,  | f(x)-L | < \epsilon_1$ where $\epsilon_1=\frac{ \varepsilon }{2. | M | }>0$. And similarly you can say the same about $\delta_2$ because$\;\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = M$ Now, when I give you some real value of epsilon you can always find these two deltas and hence their minimum because they exist (as the limits of $f$ and $g$ at $a$ exist).

Comment: But that is exactly what i was supposing! Maybe i skipped some steps, but im keeping in my mind that the δ1 and the δ2 could have been defined if i did some more steps. By saying what you are saying, it looks like you are telling me that the reasoning i explained in my post is correct, but i simply just do not state the way i can REALLY define the deltas. Is that the case? If it is, why every proof bothers in defining δ1<1, if they could just define it on the basis of some ε? I'm sorry, but i really would love to understand this! Thank you!

Comment: There's one more problem in your proof, since $L$ and $M$ can be zero, instead of taking $\frac{\epsilon}{2|M|}$ as $\epsilon_1$(see my last comment) you should take  $\small \frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|M|)}$ and in the later step $\small | M | . | f(x)-L |<|M|\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|M|)}<(1+|M)|\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|M|)}=\frac{\epsilon}2$ whereas earlier you were cancelling $|M|$. Now your proof seems correct to me. "why every proof bothers in defining δ1<1".. That is not a botherance for them. "if they could just define it on the basis of some ε" Yes, they could and they do!

Comment: The thing that matters is you should be able to make $f(x)g(x)$ arbitrarily close to $LM$(as close as you like) by taking $x$ to be sufficiently close to $a$(on either side of a) but not $a$. For showing that..yes we can make $f(x)g(x)$ arbitrarily close to $LM$, you need to show how, and for that you say, by taking $x$ in the $\delta-$ neighborhood of $a$. (and this $\delta$ hence $\delta-$ neighborhood should always exists for any given $\epsilon-$ neighborhood of $LM$ (arbitrary closeness)). For this reason, $\delta$ is chosen to be constant or some function of epsilon.

Comment: But in this proof, $\delta$ is minimum of 2 deltas and these deltas always exist for any $\epsilon>0$ because the limits of $f$ and $g$ at $a$ exists, therefore your $\delta>0$ always exists too. Since the existence is proved.The limit is proved. Further clarification:"... your delta restrictions would have some x′s on them" No your delta doesn't have any $x$ in it (and choice of delta should be independent of $x$, if not, then there would be a problem).Since you delta=$\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$where these 2 deltas are coming from already given limits & always exist, don't have any $x$ in it

Comment: Ok! thank you so much! From that i infer that my exposition proves the limit but i should have refered that my deltas can be garanteed to exist only because the limits of f(x) and g(x) exist. That is, in the way i write my proof,  i'm assuming that the deltas exist, but i have to explicitly say the they existe, because im assuming lim f(x)= L and lim g(x)=M. Is that it?

Comment: Yes exactly that. Limits $\small \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)= L ,\; \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = M$ are given, which imply $\delta_1, \delta_2$ exist respectively. Further Advice: edit the question tag and add "proof verification". You can write an answer to your own question with the modified error less proof by making some necessary changes indicated in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Appreciate it!